# How to insert an existing IQueryable element to a ThenInclude method in EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

How do I insert an existing `IQueryable` element in a `ThenInclude` method?

```
public IQueryable<Store> Store => GetDbSet<Store>()
        .Include(st => st.App)
            .ThenInclude(app => app.Client)
                .ThenInclude(cl => cl.Country)
                    .ThenInclude(co => co.Culture)
        .Include(st => st.Features)
            .ThenInclude(this.StoreFeatures);

public IQueryable<StoreFeatures> StoreFeatures => GetDbSet<StoreFeatures>()
        .Include(ft => ft.Cultures)
            .ThenInclude(ct => ct.Culture);
```

Comment: What do you mean about "existing IQueryable"? Your issue still isn't clear to me

Comment: @ArmanEbrahimpour the code displays the issue. how to add StoreFeatures to the TheInclude method

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question.

The problem is that `Include` / `ThenInclude` chain is not composable. In theory the chain can be extracted from the `IQueryable` expression and then `Include` to be transformed to `ThenInclude`.

But that's not enough. All these calls return `IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, TProperty>`, where the `TEntity` is from the original `IQueryable`. Hence the `ThneInclude` calls also need to be remapped.

Another problem is when the includable chain contains multiple `Include` calls. Every `Include` except the first "restarts" the chain, hence should apply the original chain before converting it to `ThenInclude`.

With that being said, following is a sample implementation which does that:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query;

namespace Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
{
    public static class IncludeExtensions
    {
        const string IncludeMethodName = nameof(EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.Include);
        const string ThenIncludeMethodName = nameof(EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ThenInclude);

        public static IQueryable<TEntity> ThenInclude<TEntity, TProperty>(
            this IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, IEnumerable<TProperty>> source,
            IQueryable<TProperty> includes) => source.Include(includes);

        public static IQueryable<TEntity> ThenInclude<TEntity, TProperty>(
            this IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, TProperty> source,
            IQueryable<TProperty> includes) => source.Include(includes);

        static IQueryable<TEntity> Include<TEntity, TProperty>(
            this IQueryable<TEntity> source, IQueryable<TProperty> includes)
        {
            var targetChain = GetIncludeChain(includes.Expression);
            if (targetChain.Count == 0) return source;
            var sourceChain = GetIncludeChain(source.Expression);
            var result = source.Expression;
            foreach (var targetInclude in targetChain)
            {
                bool isInclude = targetInclude.Method.Name == IncludeMethodName;
                if (isInclude && result != source.Expression)
                {
                    result = sourceChain.Aggregate(result, (r, i) =>
                        Expression.Call(i.Method, r, i.Arguments[1]));
                }
                var typeArgs = targetInclude.Method.GetGenericArguments();
                var prevPropertyType = isInclude ? typeof(TProperty) : typeArgs[1];
                var propertyType = typeArgs[isInclude ? 1 : 2];
                result = Expression.Call(
                    typeof(EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions), ThenIncludeMethodName,
                    new[] { typeof(TEntity), prevPropertyType, propertyType },
                    result, targetInclude.Arguments[1]);
            }
            return source.Provider.CreateQuery<TEntity>(result);
        }

        static Stack<MethodCallExpression> GetIncludeChain(Expression source)
        {
            var result = new Stack<MethodCallExpression>();
            while (source is MethodCallExpression methodCall && methodCall.IsIncludeOrThenInclude())
            {
                result.Push(methodCall);
                source = methodCall.Arguments[0];
            }
            return result;
        }

        static bool IsIncludeOrThenInclude(this MethodCallExpression source)
            => source.Method.DeclaringType == typeof(EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions)
                && source.Method.IsGenericMethod
                && (source.Method.Name == IncludeMethodName || source.Method.Name == ThenIncludeMethodName);
    }
}
```

The two custom `ThenInclude` method overloads are to support both reference and collection navigation properties (similar to the standart `ThenInclude` overloads).

Now your sample will compile and will insert the second query includes into the the first query include chain.