# EF Core IQueryable Extensions for Includes

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, iqueryable, ef-core-3.1

I am using Entity Framework Core 3.1.8 and I have two complex types in my data model. Let's call them `Book` and `Author`. Each has its own IQueryable extensions class for loading all its navigation properties:

```
public static IQueryable<Book> IncludeNavigationProperties(this IQueryable<Book> books)
    {
        return books.Include(b => b.RelatedProperty)
                .ThenInclude(rp => rp.SomeOtherProperty)
                // include all the other properties
                ;
    }
```

These are used by various methods in the repository:

```
public async Task<Model.Book> GetBookByIDAsync(long bookID)
    {
        var book = await context.Book
            .IncludeNavigationProperties()
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(b => b.BookID = bookID);

        return mapper.Map<Model.Book>(book);
    }
```

I am trying to figure out a way to use both extension method when loading an author and its related books to avoid having to duplicate the code. Something like:

```
public async Task<Model.Author> GetAuthorByIDAsync(long authorID)
    {
        var author = await context.Author
            .IncludeNavigationProperties()
            .Include(a => a.Books)
             // then include all of the book's navigation properties
             // using the existing extension method rather than duplicating
             // the code here
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.AuthorID= authorID);

        return mapper.Map<Model.Author>(author);
    }
```

Is there some good way to do this without duplicating the code?

Comment: Doubt it's possible, since you need to call different method (`ThenInclude`) instead of `Include` in `IncludeNavigationProperties` in second case. You can add separate `ThenIncludeNavigationProperties` method though and duplicate code there, but it's better than duplicate it at every call site.

Comment: Possible, but it needs reflection magic for a few hours. Call should looks like `IncludeRelated(IncludeNavigationProperties)` and implementation should create correct expression tree.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62368932/how-to-insert-an-existing-iqueryable-element-to-a-theninclude-method-in-ef-core/62372927#62372927. The usage is a bit weird, but works :) `.Include(a => a.Books).ThenInclude(context.Books.IncludeNavigationProperties())`

Comment: @IvanStoev, nice. I can reuse part of your code.